How to delete every weekend occurrence of an daily event in Outlook
Summary

I recently joined a new team and my manager added me to the 'daily meeting' event
The event has been setup to repeat at 10am every day, Mon-Sun
This is annoying as the event also occurs on the weekends, and triggers a reminder on my phone
I want to delete every instance/occurrence of the event that falls on a Saturday/Sunday

Calendar Visual


The image above shows how the event currently appears in my diary
The ❌ icons show the occurrences I would like to delete

Solution path 1 (non-technical, amend meeting):

I realise that the easiest thing would be to amend the re-occurrence setting and simply de-select Sat/Sun...
However as a meeting recipient (and not organiser) I cannot modify the series/occurrence information

Solution path 2 (non-technical, ask organiser to change):

Logically, I also considered asking the meeting organiser to amend the series for everyone...
However, the meeting was created by a director 4 years ago and has been sent to 20+ people in that time. This makes it very awkward, as the newest joiner, to ask my boss's boss to change this long-standing invite that seemingly no-one else has had a problem with in the past 4 years

Solution path 3 (technical, VBA):
With other option paths seeming blocked, I have resorted to trying to fix this technically (i.e. with VBA) however I need some help please...
Scripts / answers reviewed before asking:

S/U: How to change recurring meeting series without cancelling exceptions
S/O: VBA: Outlook calendar - omit single (deleted) recurring event
Remove specific set of days (i.e. every Friday) from recurring meetings
Delete Old Calendar Events using VBA
Delete old instance of a recurring meeting, but do not delete new instances
How do we delete or modify only future events with Outlook recurring events?


Not sure what you are asking, but you should be able to programmatically delete weekend instances or modify the recurrence pattern. Just keep in mind that a new meeting update/notification coming from the organizer will revert your changes.

If you are receiving meeting notifications via Microsoft Teams on your phone. You can set Quiet time during which you will not receive any notifications, including meeting reminders.
Steps how to do it:

Turn on the Teams app on your phone;
Press top left corner with your profile picture;
Notifications;
Under block notifications choose Quiet time, set quiet time on Saturdays and Mondays;
Make sure Set on Teams and Outlook is checked;
Enjoy your quiet time!


Option Explicit

Private Sub DeleteWeekendAppointments()
    
    Dim myFolder As folder
    Dim myItems As Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    
    Dim delItems As Long
    
    Set myFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items
    
    'include recurring items
    '-------------------------
    myItems.Sort ("[Start]")
    myItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
    '-------------------------
    
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim srchSubject As String
    
    srchSubject = "Test weekend delete"
    strFilter = "[Subject] = '" & srchSubject & "'"
    Debug.Print vbCr & "strFilter: " & strFilter
    
    Set myItem = myItems.Find(strFilter)
    
    If Not myItem Is Nothing Then
    
        If myItem.Class = olAppointment Then
            
            'Debug.Print "myItem.Start: " & myItem.Start
            
            Select Case Weekday(myItem.Start)
                       
                Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                    Debug.Print " myItem.Start: " & myItem.Start
                    myItem.Delete
                    delItems = delItems + 1
                    Debug.Print "  Weekend appointments processed: " & delItems
                    Debug.Print
                    
            End Select
            
        End If
        
    Else
        Debug.Print "No items."
    End If
    
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        
        If delItems > 103 Then
            GoTo noInfiniteLoop  ' no end date
        End If
        
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        
        If Not myItem Is Nothing Then
            
            If myItem.Class = olAppointment Then
            
                'Debug.Print "myItem.Start: " & myItem.Start
                
                Select Case Weekday(myItem.Start)
                           
                    Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                        Debug.Print " myItem.Start: " & myItem.Start
                        myItem.Delete
                        delItems = delItems + 1
                        Debug.Print "  Weekend appointments processed: " & delItems
                        Debug.Print
                End Select
            
            End If
        
        Else
            Debug.Print "No more items."
        End If
        
    Wend

noInfiniteLoop:

    Debug.Print vbCr & "Weekend appointments processed: " & delItems
    Debug.Print vbCr & "Done."
    
End Sub

